# UnityEngine.Component' does not contain a definition for `velocity'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am following [this tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter-tutorial/moving-player?playlist=17147) of Unity space shooter chapter 1-6 moving ship.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour 
{
    // Use this for initialization
    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
        Rigidbody.velocity = movement;
    }
}
```

The code I wrote is exactly same but I get the following error:

> Unity Error: UnityEngine.Component' does not contain a definition for `velocity'

Comment: Could it be that `Rigidbody` should have a lower case r ?

Comment: did you attach rigidbody componet to game object?

Comment: Yes I attached rigidbody component and small r didn't work

Comment: Sorry for all I think I found the solution. The problem was that the guide I saw was just out dated. It was for Unity 4..I am using Unity 5 and there was new script example. I am going to try it. Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `rigidbody` instead of `Rigidbody`. Currently you are accessing the class `Rigidbody` instead of the class member `rigidbody`.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour 
{
    // Use this for initialization
    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
        rigidbody.velocity = movement;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, sir, but I got the same error. I tried "GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = movement" and I got no error. But it behaves oddly.

Comment: Sir,  i just found new Unity 5 guide so I am goint to follow it. The guide I saw was for Unity 4. It was just out dated. Sorry for stupid question. For give me....

Comment: Make sure that you have added a Rigidbody component to your PlayerControl. You can do this via the add component button when you have your PlayerControl selected in the editor

Comment: @PoorGuy Don't use `GetComponent` in `FixedUpdate` if you can help it. `GetComponent` is an expensive operation, so it is better to call it sparingly. It would be better to add a `private Rigidbody` field and assign to it in `Start` if possible.

Comment: @PoorGuy also Unity 5 is actually already "old" maybe you should search for a tutorial that fits the version you are using...